# How do I interrupt the NEW process, then return to it?

Tags: visual-workflow, button-overrides, classic

I've been asked to display a text message before creating a new opportunity.  In my use case, a user clicks NEW, and before the New opportunity standard page opens, he views a message.   That message is created in a FLOW, and launched using a Visual Force page to override the NEW button on Opportunity.
WHen I use this code in Lightning it works-  the message displays, and when the user clicks 'finish' s/he is directed to the standard New Opportunity page.

```
<apex:page>
<flow:interview name="NewOpportunityMessage" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?nooverride=1')}"/>
</apex:page>
```

But when I try this in CLASSIC it doesn't work.  I get redirected to the NEW opportunity page, but the FLOW doesn't seem to run.  Here's the code that produces this result:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New,null,null,true)}">
<flow:interview name="NewOpportunityMessage"></flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

What do I need to do to get the FLOW to run, and then display the standard NEW Opportunity page in Salesforce CLASSIC?

Thanks!
Wayne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action on apex:page will cause an immediate redirect to the new opportunity page, without running the flow or anything else. Use the first version of the code instead (`finishLocation=...`). As an aside, you should be able to use the **same** code for both environments...

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
<flow:interview name="NewOpportunityMessage" finishLocation="{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New, null, null, true)}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Brilliant!  That works.     Thanks for taking time to help here.